# How can I use my own custom styled text boxes in the ASP.NET login control?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, authentication

I have some experience with ASP.NET, and this is my second time using the log in control. In this project, I'm using a bootstrap toolbar that has the log in control on the side of the toolbar. The thing is, unless I can **add bootstrap styling and take out some parts of the log in control**, I **need a way to assign log in functions to my preexisting boxes**.

I know that I could try to re-code the log in function, but like I said, I'm a beginner and I'm not sure that I could keep all the functionality or get it to work period. Are there any simpler solutions? If not, are there any good tutorials on re-coding from scratch?

Screenshot of my toolbar (Ignore the other login function, it's for playing around with):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the ASP.NET login control with a template which gives some ability to customise the layout and styling:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178340%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178339%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

You might also find this tutorial handy: http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-with-asp-net

I haven't tried it myself, but there's a project to provide Twitter Bootstrap controls for ASP.NET: https://github.com/pmcfernandes/BootstrapControls

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful, I forgot about templating!